# Is this a logical fallacy or is this valid argumentation

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality

Say there is some real valued function $f:R\to R$  such that $f(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$. Then there is some maximal $t_0>0$ such that  $|f(t)| < 1$ for all $t \in (0,t_0)$. Furthermore, I have
$$
|f(t)| \leq C t \quad \text{for all} \quad t>0 \text{ such that } |f(t)|<1
$$
for some $C>0$ independent of $t$. Assuming all this, I want to estimate a maximal $t_0>0$ such that 
$$
|f(t)|<1 \quad \text{for all} \quad t \in (0,t_0)
$$

Can I conclude from this inequality, that
$$
t_0\geq \frac{1}{C}
$$
or is this an error in reasoning?

Comment: Why would you conclude that? What are the steps you take when getting to the last inequality? In other words, what is the reasoning you're doing?

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(t) = t$ satisfies $|f(t)|\le 2t$.  Take $C=2$.  It also satisfies $|f(t)| < 1$ for all $t \in (0,\frac{1}{100})$.  Take $t_0 = \frac{1}{100}$.  However we may not conclude $\frac{1}{100} > \frac{1}{2}$.  You did not say that $t_0$ was chosen as large as possible.

Comment: That $f(t) \leq C t$ for $t \in (0,t_0)$ is another assumption not the part I am trying to conclude. I want to use this to estimate $t_0 $ from below.

Comment: New example now.